# could not find function "flextable_to_rmd"

Tags: r

```
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
ft <- autofit(ft)

for(i in 1:2){
  flextable_to_rmd(ft)
}
```

Error:
could not find function "flextable_to_rmd".

This error arises when when knitting to html file.
This code was taken from flextable book. pandoc version I have 2.14.0.3. is there any function/code am I missing here?

Comment: Is there any chance that you didn't run the function call for the library? If you're sure you did, did you get any errors in the console? If that is also a no, then add the library to the function, like `flextable::flextable_to_rmd` and see if that works.

Comment: I am sure, I ran library. Error in console:  Error in flextable_to_rmd(ft) : 
  could not find function "flextable_to_rmd".

Comment: flextable::flextable_to_rmd:      Error: 'flextable_to_rmd' is not an exported object from 'namespace:flextable'

Comment: What version of `flextable` do you have? I have version 0.7.0. Is the chunk option `results="asis"` set for the R chunk this code is in?

Comment: Already had results="asis".  After updating to flextable 7.1.12 and officer 4.3.1, it worked. Thank you.